# Image from ImageField doesn't load in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-models

This is the DJ Model

```
class DJ(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='/img/', height_field=None, width_field=None)
```

This is how I am saving an instance of a DJ

```
dj = DJ(name=name, rank=rank, img='/img/'+rank+'.jpg')
dj.save()
```

The MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL are

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'c:/jaskaran/dropbox/edmhunters/hunt/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have included this in the urls.py file

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is the how i am accesing the image in the template file

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ dj.img }}" class="img-rounded"/>
```

When I see the source code

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/img/1.jpg` the image is displayed in the browser, but it doesn't show in the template.

EDIT - When I inspect the image element the address is shown as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/1.jpg`. Why doesn't the `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` work as it's supposed to be?

Comment: dj var is sent correctly to the view?

Comment: Yes, the DJ name and rank is displayed correctly.

Comment: what shows "{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ dj.img }}" and "{{ dj.img.url }}" ?

Comment: Thanks {{dj.img.url}} works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `{{ dj.img.url }}` instead of `{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ dj.img }}` works.